# Can two usb gaming controllers be wired together to act as one?

Tags: usb-device

Let's say I have two USB gaming controllers. Those generic ones.

Is it possible to make it so they work as one? So if you press Left in Controller one and B on controller 2, they both get sent and identified as if were sent from the same controller.

I honestly think it wouldn't work because of drivers, and maybe because of the power loss considering it is now shared by two similar devices.

Comment: They each show up as a different COM port to the master device, yes? So you have a conflict there to start. Not to mention intereference on the +/- data lines when both try to send data at the same time.   Maybe if you use a hub, and IF the host accepts two controllers for one game.

Comment: It is actually a project that I am still getting the specifics. I would want to modify one controller but allow an unmodified one to send the same signal. You know like if you plug two usb keyboards and if you press letters in any of them have the same effect? Something like that.

Comment: But as mentioned in the question, I think it wouldn't work, so I'll try a workaround. I was just making sure. Thank you.

Comment: most likely depends on the game system and the game itself

Comment: You cannot just wire the D+ and D- together for both the controllers and stick that into a USB port. You could create a device that accepts 2 inputs and does a logical "OR" of the buttons (and maybe an average of the analog sticks) and reports back to the host as a single device, but it isn't as simple as "wiring them together to act as one", this involves some active components and smarts.

Comment: Even with normal operation, this may be possible for some games/emulators.  Applications that allow multiple keybinds and support controllers allow you to bind multiple controllers to one player.

Comment: This is what Windows does with mice, so it obviously can be done in software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be handled by software. Either the OS, a driver or middleman software, or the game. Many games allow you to arbitrarily assign one or multiple buttons to an action, regardless from which source. Some middleman programs can intercept and override the controllers to turn joystick events into keyboard events.

Some controllers have a usb keyboard mode that would work too.

But a hardwired usb physical method? Short of replacing it's hardware so the physical buttons are wired together, no.

Comment: Or you could make a gizmo that has two USB in and one out, that does the button combining.  It'd be a *lot* of work.

Comment: Is this entirely true? I have a USB barcode reader and an USB keyboard on my computer - the application can't tell if I've typed a number on the keyboard or scanned a barcode. What happens if I plug in two keyboards? A better question is _how does the application/OS etc know which controller is which?_ (I would expect them to be identical - is it the port they're enumerated on, or a serial numbers?)

Comment: The OS treats all keyboard scancodes the same. That's jow. But usb hid keyboards are not usb hid joysticks. That's a different usb profile.

Comment: I think it will be easier to add additional ways to trigger a button in one controller(by wiring the contacts with an external thing) than merge two controllers as one. Thanks!